# Hot reload the configuration available on S3 for AWS Fargate Springboot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, amazon-s3, aws-fargate

I have a springboot application deployed on AWS ECS using `Fargate`, the configuration for this application is stored on `S3 bucket` (`.env` file), while creating a task definition we are pointing S3 ARN of the env file in the Environment Files option in for the container.

Everything works fine, but I am facing issues when configuration changes on S3 bucket, the application which is already running in Fargate not picking up the latest changes which are available in S3 Bucket.

Looking for a solution where any changes to S3 configuration immediately hot reload the springboot app and pointing to the new changes. Is there anyway to achieve this without using `spring-cloud-config server`.